# pub trait Any: 'static, what is static? Is it a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I am currently reading the code for Rusts implementation of `std::any::Any`.

Here is the declaration of the trait.

```
pub trait Any: 'static
```

If my understanding is correct, this defines a trait `Any` which **inherits from** everything which follows the colon `':'` character.

In this case, here we have `'static`.

The quote character `'` suggests to me this is a lifetime declaration.

I want to understand how to interpret this.

I assumed that traits could only inherit from other traits. This ***may*** suggest that `'static` is a trait. Is that correct?

If not, and `'static` is a lifetime specification and not a trait, then how should I interpret this line of code? What are the consequences of `'static`? What behavior does it enforce about `Any` ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no trait inheritance in Rust. The syntax `: ...` in trait definitions defines bounds that an implementor has to fulfill. In case of a lifetime, it's a lifetime bound.

In this case it means for an object to implement `Any` it has to satisfy the lifetime bound `'static` i.e. it may not be or contain a reference that lives shorter than `'static`.
And even more specifically the compiler does implement `Any` for every type that does fulfill that bound.

Comment: FWIW the implementation of `Any` for any type that does fulfill that bound is [this one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-Any-for-T).

Comment: @FreelanceConslutant would you kindly point out where in that document it says anything about inheritance? My browser coldn't find `inherit` anywhere.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant This is not inheritance, those are supertrait bounds. They're equvialent to `where` bounds, just like `: 'static`. The only difference between them and other `where` clauses is that supertrait's methods can be called on trait objects, and on nightly, upcasting is also possible.

Comment: That's what inheritance is. A is a B is the same as A is bound by B.

Comment: But that's not how bounds work, they're more like for `S` to implement `T`, `S` has to implement `U` as well.